# Extracting CCITTTFaxDecode image from PDF with DecodeParm EncodedByteAlign=true

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a PDF that I'm trying to extract images from into a C# Bitmap object (not a file).  I'm using iTextSharp 5.4.0.  I have noticed that any image with EncodeByteAlign=true as a Decode Parameter gets decoded as an all white raster.

This is what the PDF Object looks like.

```
17 0 obj 
<<
/DecodeParms 
<<
/Rows 234
/Columns 417
/EndOfLine false
/BlackIs1 false
/EncodedByteAlign true
/K -1
>>
/ImageMask true
/Width 417
/BitsPerComponent 1
/Height 234
/Subtype /Image
/Filter /CCITTFaxDecode
/Length 1925
/Type /XObject
>>
```

I'm guessing there is a bug in the TIFFFaxDecoder.cs file in the DecodeT6() method but I'm not sure how to fix it.

My question is, has anyone seen this problem and worked around it successfully with iTextSharp (not other external libraries)?

I can send the file if anyone is interested in seeing it.

Thanks,
Darren